# nodejs latest 7.8 has crashed with expressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

After upgrading my node from 6.9 to 7.8, my express app has broken:

```
$ nodemon                                                                                                                                                                                   
[nodemon] 1.11.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[nodemon] watching: *.*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
/var/www/html/expresss-app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83                                                                                                                                                                          
        throw e                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Error: The module '/var/www/html/expresss-app/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/var/www/html/expresss-app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/expresss-app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/expresss-app/models/user.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message tells you both the reason _and_ the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You should rebuild your dependencies every time you upgrade Node.

Run `npm rebuild` or`npm install` in your app's directory.

You can also remove the `node_module` and run `npm install` from scratch.

This is actually explained in the very error message that you quoted in your question:

```
Error: The module '/var/www/html/expresss-app/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
```

Hint: Read the error messages before you post them on Stack Overflow next time. They may include all of the info that you need, like in this case.